# ionic info command exits without any error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I got a new laptop and I installed node, ionic and angular. I added ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME in environment. ionic version is 6.20.2, node version is v16.17.1 and angular version is 14.2.4 and npm version is 8.15.0. When I use ionic serve, application opens in browser. But when I use `ionic info`, it exits without any error. Same happens when I try `ionic cap build android`. [image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I'm on Linux, with ionic cli 6.20.2 and node 18.12.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when generating the build for Android, the command ended without any error message or warning.

After many tests it was only solved by downgrading.

```
npm install --global @ionic/cli@6.20.1
```